# Post navigation sorting in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In function.php I added this coding for sorting number wise display, it's working fine.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse183601_filter_category_query',10, 3 );
function wpse183601_filter_category_query( $query ) {
    // only modify front-end category archive pages
    if( is_category() && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        //$query->set( 'posts_per_page','20' );
        $query->set( 'orderby','meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key','question_number' );
        $query->set( 'order','ASC' );
    }

}
```

but navigation displayed admin order wise

I have added this query but prev, next navigation working in admin view
navigation will display question_number order wise question_number is custom field

How to fix it?

Comment: do you want to display by question_number in admin?

Comment: no, it'll display in frontend

Comment: can you post your wp_query arguments?

Comment: yes, wp-Query arguments are correct, In frontend view ex:1,2,3 meta_value wise display in admin view 2,4,3 then prev next navigation display admin view wise that's the problem